# Is there a way to copy fingerprints, etc from windows hello to an other computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-hello

I've configured Windows hello on my computer to log in with my fingerprint. Now I want to copy this data to other computers, so that I am not forced to run the setup manually at every computer. Is this possible?

Comment: Interesting question from security point of view, +1. According to this [not very technical article](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10-windows-hello-and-privacy), MS doesn't store actual fingereprint image...